# is there a way to make available a matlab package to all functions available in same .m file

Tags: matlab

I am working with matlab packages and I want to make a package available to all methods in same .m file. I am trying to import the package in main method of .m file and it seems to me that other functions in .m file are unable to access the package. I do not want to import package in all functions and want to avoid this situation. Is there a way to tackle this issue.

Comment: Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html

Comment: @Adriaan: folder containing package is already in set path of matlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: no. Unfortunately, in MATLAB you must always use the fully qualified name of a function, even if you're in the same packaged (or else use `import` statements).

Note that adding the `+mypackage` directory to the MATLAB path doesn't work - you'll get the warning:

```
>> addpath +mypackage
Warning: Package directories not allowed in MATLAB path: +mypackage
> In path (line 109)
  In addpath (line 88)
```